# Use induction and elimination rules of propositional logic to prove

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I was asked to prove p -> q |- ¬p or q by nature induction

1. $p \rightarrow q$         premise
2. p                        assume
3. q                        $\rightarrow e,1$
4. $¬ p \rightarrow ¬ q$
5. ¬p                       assume
6. ¬p or q                   or-i, 3-5

is it correct?

Comment: No "induction" at all...

Comment: You can see [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rule_of_Material_Implication) as well as in many many similar posts in this site.

Comment: The rules of inference in a natural deduction system are of *introduction* and elimination of the connectives (or quantifiers).

Answer (score 2):

No

Where does (4) come from? And you haven't discharged your assumptions (2) and (5).

Hint: use a reductio proof -- i.e. assume $\neg(\neg p \lor q)$ and derive a contradiction ...